# Finding Large Primes: code is running so slow can't figure out how to make it run faster

Tags: python, optimization

---

```
start = 100000000
end = 100000050
for i in range(start, end+1):
    if i > 100000000:
        for j in range(2, i):
            if isinstance(i**0.5, int) or (i % j == 0):
             break
        else:
            print(i)
```

---

I'm new to python and I'm trying to find the first prime number bigger than 100 million. I need to figure out how to make it run faster.

Comment: Well for starters `range(2, i)` is looping through 100 million integers. That's going to be slow

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement? Why not just set `start = 100000001`?

Comment: `isinstance(i**0.5, int)` will never be true. Raising to a fractional power always returns a float, even if `i` is a perfect square.

Comment: @Wondercricket It only has to loop through all 100 million integers when the number is prime. Otherwise, it stops when it finds the first factor.

Comment: You can improve the inner loop with `range(2, int(i**0.5)+1)`

Comment: [This more general primes thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) on SO might be relevant.

Comment: which one is the inner loop ?

Comment: thank you @Barmar it runs a lot faster but I can't make it give me Just  the One Prime bigger than 100 million I can't make it stop unless I manually reset the end to be one greater than the prime number but I I kind of want it so that it gives it to me without me  forcing it to you know and I want to make it more robust

Comment: You have to break out of the outer loop when the inner loop finds a prime.

Comment: well I need to do is have it stopped after a prints once that has been the biggest problem so far

Comment: The inner loop is `for j`, the outer loop is `for i`

Comment: plain trial division is the slower way possible to check if a given number, specially a big one, is prime or not. You need a more powerful test like the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants_of_the_test). Relevant [numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MscGSN5J6o)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find the first prime, break out of the outer loop when the inner loop finds a prime.

```
start = 100000001
end = 100000050
for i in range(start, end+1):
    for j in range(2, int(i ** 0.5)+1):
        if (i % j == 0):
            break # stop inner loop
    else:
        print(i)
        break # stop outer loop
else:
    print("No prime found")
```

Comment: all I wanted to do is print only a integer of the prime number and  with this code it only repeats printing that number

Comment: I just tried it, and it just printed `100000007` once.

Comment: Did you leave out the second `break`?